# Linear transformations and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a linear transformation $T: V->W$ and such that ${u1,u2,u3}$ are in $V$ and are linearly independent, will ${T(u1),T(u2),T(u3)}$ be linearly independent?
Well I've found that yes , because take $T(c1u1)+T(c2u2)+T(c3u3)= T(c1u1+c2u2+c3u3)=0$, => $c1u1+C2u2+c3u3=0$ but u1, u2 and u3 are linearly independent therefore c1=c2=c3=0 and then  ${T(u1),T(u2),T(u3)}$ will be linearly independent. Is this right? If it is, What if we have that the $dim V > dim W$ ?

Comment: Even when $T=0$? Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you clarify the answer please?

Comment: If $T=0$, then $T(u_1)=T(u_2)=T(u_3)=0$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: and if they are not $1-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not true that if $u_i$ are linerly independent then $T(u_i)$ are linearly independent.

It's true in general only if the Null(T)=0, that if if the associated matrix is full column rank.

Comment: and in that case?

Comment: Oh so if it is only $1-1$

Comment: Yes in this case you are sure that also $T(u_i)$ are linearly independent. Whereas in $Null(T)\neq0$ you might have some $u_i$ which leads to the zero vector.